# Can you provide additional help for common parameters in a PowerShell script?

Tags: powershell, parameters

I wrote a script which uses `Write-Verbose` and the common parameter `-verbose`.
Now I would like to give the user additional information about what happens when they specify `-verbose` via `Get-Help`. I tried to do it like regular parameters, but when I run `Get-Help` in the script it doesn't get picked up.

```
<#
.PARAMETER verbose
Help text for Get-Help
#>
```

Is there some way to nicely present the help text or do I have to "abuse" .DESCRIPTION?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible and you seem to have confirmed that.

Rather than use `DESCRIPTION` I might consider `NOTES` as a section where you could include this information.

Alternatively, if adding `-Verbose` primarily affects the operation of one existing parameter, it may be best to include the information in *that* parameter's inline help.

One other thing I'll note: you probably don't want that information to be associated with the `-Verbose` *parameter* anyway, as that's not the only way that verbose output will be shown.

If the caller set `$VerbosePreference` to see verbose output for example, the `-Verbose` parameter will not be bound, however the conditions will still be correct to show it.

Answer (score 0):

An advanced function defined by either the `[CmdletBinding]` attribute or at least one parameter decorated with `[Parameter]` attribute already includes the common parameters so you can't define it again.

If you make it a simple function instead of an advanced function, you can define it separately.

```
function Test-Function {

    <#
        .PARAMETER verbose
        Additional help text for Get-Help
    #>

    param (
        [switch]
        $Verbose
    )
    
    begin {
        
    }
    
    process {
        
    }
    
    end {
        
    }
}

Get-Help Test-Function -Full
```

It is generally not a good idea to use automatic/reserved variable names.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The common parameters (Verbose included) is a defined  set of words that apply to all scripts, these also have their own sections in the predefined commandbased help.
Unless there is a way to change this output via custom controls (with [formating files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/custom-formatting-files?view=powershell-7.1) ), you will have to get around this with the ordinary parameters of the [comment based help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comment_based_help?view=powershell-7.1)